# Is it possible to link in multiple steps / is linking "associative"?

Tags: c, linker

I'm trying to figure out whether it's possible to link object files together in multiple steps, provided that the "order" is preserved. (Alternatively, whether linking* is "associative" or not).

*I'm vaguely aware that there are some subtleties to linking like linker scripts, weak symbols &c. I'm mostly curious about what happens in the simplest case for an "ordinary" C project where every symbol is unique.

I have a trivial project with the following structure:

```
.
├── build.sh
├── child.c
├── child.h
├── grandparent.c
├── grandparent.h
├── main.c
├── parent.c
└── parent.h
```

It's built using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# build objects
gcc -c -o grandparent.o grandparent.c
gcc -c -o parent.o parent.c
gcc -c -o child.o child.c
gcc -c -o main.o main.c

# link all at once
gcc -o main main.o grandparent.o parent.o child.o
```

Here's `child.h`

```
int c_add();
```

And `child.c`

```
#include "child.h"
int c_add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
```

Here's `parent.c`

```
#include "parent.h"
int p_add(int x, int y) { return c_add(x, y); }
```

and `grandparent.c`

```
#include "grandparent.h"
int gp_add(int x, int y) { return p_add(x, y); }
```

(`parent.h` and `grandparent.h` are trivial variations of `child.h`)

I'm trying to figure out whether it's possible to link the four object files of the project together in three steps, like in the following (strawman syntax):

```
$ combine-objfile -o bar.o parent.o child.o
$ combine-objfile -o foo.o main.o grandparent.o
$ gcc -o main foo.o bar.o
```

Where `combine-objfile` is a hypothetical utility that combines two files of whatever-format-a-.o-is into another file of the same format, satisfying the same invariants (and allowing references to not-yet-defined symbols)

In case the answer is platform-specific, I'm most curious about x86 Linux.

Comment: combine-objfile is `ar`

Comment: @user3528438 Does that create an archive containing individual object files (a `.a` file (?)) or a bona fide “combined object file” that’s indistinguishable from one produced by `gcc -c`? It might do both depending on the arguments, I just don’t know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It may not be associative in the mathematical sense, but you likely do not really need that.

The macOS and Linux link command (`ld`) has a switch, `-r`, that says to link into a new object file instead of an executable.

Answer (score 1):

"Linking" is the process of constructing *an executable* from one or more object files.  It is possible in principle to combine multiple object files in a way that leaves some symbols unresolved, but, to a first approximation, the result is not an executable, and therefore what you have done in that case is not linking.

In practice, one does not generally combine multiple object files into a single, monolithic, non-executable object file.  Instead, one builds libraries.  It is indeed possible to add objects to a library incrementally, but build systems are not usually structured to do that, because it's not very useful.  Instead, if one wants a library, one generally builds all the objects that will go into it first, and then forms the library from them.  Occasionally, that involves adding the contents of one library to another, but rarely does it involve adding objects to an existing library.

Comment: `one does not generally combine multiple object files into a single, monolithic, non-executable object file` ... but is it possible? The main thing I'm trying to figure out is "how possible it is to parallelize linking" ... since I can remember hearing that linking is a bottleneck on some large projects (and I'm trying to figure out why "doing the obvious thing" and combining some object files together before finally producing an executable doesn't work).

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but it doesn't enable parallel linking.  Anyway, for a system large enough that the time spent linking matters, a better (and better-supported) approach would be to split out parts into separate shared libraries, which *can* be constructed independently.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Partial linking does allow parallel linking. Unreolved references in inputs can be resolved using definitions available in the partial link, while others remain unresolved. This can be used, for example, to build most of a project and then link in small easier-to-build parts later, and repeatedly with different versions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, that might enable (partial) linking in parallel with *compiling* other objects, but -- and perhaps I'm just being difficult here -- that's not the same thing as parallel linking.  If you intend to link `a.o` with `b.o` to form `ab.o`, and then to link in`c.o` to form an executable `abc`, then the linking steps are inherently serial.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: You can link a and b to ab, and c and d to cd, and later ab and cd to abcd. The first two of those are completely independent and can be done in parallel.